# Http get request not working

Tags: java, android, http

I got this code, any suggestions why it's not returning any value to the "toBeSplit" String?
I call the method this way.

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        getData();
    }
}).start();
```

Here is the actual method, i have tried 1000 ways and it just aint working..

```
private void getData() {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();    
    HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, timeout);
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, timeout);
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);
    String yourUrl = "http://www.ratemyplays.com/form.php";
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(yourUrl);
    {
        try {
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode == 200) {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream content = entity.getContent();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    builder.append(line);
                }
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    toBeSplit = builder.toString();
    split2 = toBeSplit.split(",");
}
```

Comment: Well you've got lots of exception "handling" code that just dumps a stack trace and continues - are there any stack traces in your log? (Exception "handling" code like this is generally a bad idea...)

Comment: Have you check that response got correctly??

Comment: @jon skeet i only put them there coz eclipse thought i should, and im rly new to java coding.

Comment: No, Eclipse realized that you had to either catch or declare that your method throws the exception. It's not like that's the only way you can handle exceptions. I suggest you read up on exception handling before going any further.

Comment: Under that exception in the logcat there's another "caused by" exception that's relevant to the question.

Comment: I have got rid of the error, but the http request still doesnt return any value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Code:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();    
    HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, timeout);
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, timeout);
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);
    String yourUrl = "http://www.ratemyplays.com/form.php";
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(yourUrl);
    {
        try {
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode == 200) {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream content = entity.getContent();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    builder.append(line);
                }
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    String tempstr = builder.toString();
            String str[] = tempstr.split(",");
```

Comment: how do i get the returned value into an array splitted with every ","?

Comment: I have Edited the code.          String tempstr = builder.toString();
            String str[] = tempstr.split(","); you get the array of String Splitted in str[]

Answer (score 0):

Try to split as below:

```
       try {
        response = client.execute(request);
        if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
            InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = "";
            BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(in));
            while ((line = bf.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }
            m_response = sb.toString();
            StringBuilder split = new StringBuilder();
            split =m_response.split(",");
        }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```